# How to split a variable in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, quality-assurance, uiautomation

I am quite new to Selenium IDE. I want to split an error message and extract the first word of the error message. I have used the following commands as in the image.

[image: commands I have used to split the variable]

Following are the results of the log.

12. assertText on css=.ngn with value Could not rejected OK
13. store on css=.ngn with value variable OK
14. store on 0 with value delimiter OK
15. store on javascript{storedVars['variable'].split(' ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} with value test OK
    echo: javascript{storedVars['variable'].split(' ')[storedVars['delimiter']]}

I also referred the following [article](https://elementalselenium.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/ways-of-splitting-strings-in-ide/).

Any of the above did not help me with my expected output. Please let me know a way to solve this issue. I am specifically expecting a solution to be done through Selenium IDE.

Comment: This might be an answer from stack overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537620/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-selenium-ide

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following [article](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/585/466918230).

**Note: Use ${asset} without double quotes**